# Problem using strip_tags in php

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I have used strip_tags to remove html tags from the text.

Example

```
<h1>title of article</h1><div class="body">The content goes here......</div>

outputs 

title of articleThe content goes here......
```

If you see the output title and body are joined(articleThe). I want to insert a space if the tag has been removed. Is this possible.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If all you want is to add a space where an opening tag directly follows a closing tag, you could do this:

```
$html = preg_replace('/(<\/[^>]+?>)(<[^>\/][^>]*?>)/', '$1 $2', $html);
$html = strip_tags($html);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will introduce spaces in e.g. `<b>high</b>lighted`.

Comment: @Yogu no, it doesn't: https://regex101.com/r/dK0aJ4/1