# remove html tags

Tags: php, strip-tags

Currently, I use strip_tags, to remove all html tags from the strings I process. However, I notice lately, that it joins words, which contained in the tags removed
ie

```
$str = "<li>Hello</li><li>world</li>";
$result = strip_tags($str);
echo $result;
(prints HelloWorld)
```

How can you get around this?

Comment: Well, there are no spaces anywhere in your string, why should PHP insert them (and where)? Think about it as simple replace function.

Comment: Hi Felix. I see your point. The thing is that this is something very common. Say you need to extract tags from a document, insert clean text in a db for fulltext searching. How can you assure that the content is clean and correctly formatted?

Comment: this is like chicken and egg, you want to remove the HTML tag, and yet keeping the format of original text, is hard to keep both side in balance. If you want to cater for fulltext search, there are lots  of manner ...

Comment: Found the below question, which basically solves my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482152/problem-using-strip-tags-in-php Thanks fot the help anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem using strip\_tags in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482152/problem-using-strip-tags-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

This would replace all html tags (anything in the form of < ABC >, in fact, without check if it truly is html) with a whitespace, then replace possible double whitespaces to single whitespaces and remove starting or ending whitespaces.

```
$str = preg_replace("/<.*?>/", " ", $str);
$str = trim(str_replace("  ", " ", $str));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can play around which Regex Pattern is best and what to replace :)

```
// ------------------------------------ 

function strip_html_tags($string) { 

    $string = str_replace("\r", ' ', $string); 
    $string = str_replace("\n", ' ', $string); 
    $string = str_replace("\t", ' ', $string); 
##  $string = str_replace("<li>', "\n* ", $string); 

##  $pattern = "/<.*?>/"; 
    $pattern = '/<[^>]*>/'; 

    $string= preg_replace ($pattern, ' ', $string); 

    $string= trim(preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $string));

return $string; 

}

// ------------------------------------
```

you can also add special replacements like: `'<li>'` to `"\n* "` ... or whatever :)

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off with [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

It won't remove the <>, but escape them.

Comment: Why do you want the user to enter tags for just removing them?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what output you want after stripping HTML tags. For example:

If you want the `<li>` tags to be converted in a plain list of items, I would suggest you to use `str_replace` to replace `<li>` with `*` and `</li>` with `\n`.

`strip_tags`'s proposal is to get rid of HTML tags without any other conversion.

Comment: Essentially, I want a string with all html tags removed without messing the original text (join words etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo strip_tags( str_replace( '>', '> ', $string ));
```

that should do exactly what you're looking for in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

From your code i discover that there was no initial space in between the words Hello Word and you don't expect the strip_tags function to add it for you, so for the strip_tags function to produce exactly what you want, i added a space after the first list tag and the result was Hello world.

You can copy and paste this code and run to see the difference.

```
    $str = "<li>Hello</li> <li>world</li>";
    $result = strip_tags($str);
    echo $result;
    //Expected result after Execution  is Hello world
```

Comment: because i was sent a message that i can do so, will it cause any harm? or i did the wrong thing?

Comment: No harm, but you will not get reputation points now on this answer.