# Codeigniter character_limiter and strip_tags

Tags: codeigniter, strip-tags, character-limit

Using a database show an article with html characters:

$row->article:

```
<div class="article">
As is usual also in Buenos Aires, is held in that city again the official Asterisk Advanced course with the new agenda <a href="http://www.google.com">google page</a>
</div>
```

Using: character_limiter ($row->article, 160) short text, but it happens that cuts the hyperlink, which generates an error in the html code, I used to solve the function strip_tags () ... but it shows the following:

```
<div class="article">
    As is usual also in Buenos Aires, is held in that city again the official Asterisk Advanced course with the new agendagoogle page...
    </div>
```

As you can see, the function removes the hyperlinks labels but also removes the spaces that surround.

I have read this article : [Problem using strip_tags in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482152/problem-using-strip-tags-in-php)

...but use a regular expression that is set to 2 text elements. I wonder if you could use something similar but with undefined labels. I hope your help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have what you are showing in your example as you have a space between the `<a>` start tag and the string.  This problem you link to will only manifesti f your users are adding `<div>` or similar.  Things like `<b><a><u>` etc; will have natural spaces when someone types something.

What you need to do is the following:

```
echo character_limiter(strip_tags($row->article), 160);
```

1. Strip_tags first
2. limit the characters 2nd.

Don't worry about the odd 'space' issue, it will be a result of human error anyways if they do not leave space between something like `the brown fox<a href="#">jumps over</a> the..`

An alternative to HTML is to also use markdown code (what you use on SO to type questions/answers). IT is much cleaned IMHO.

Comment: on my website, just use character_limiter (strip_tags ($ row-> article), 160); 

I do not think there is human error (in this case) as you see in the first example, the text is separated from the hyperlink label.

Comment: @user1151980, in your example you should not have `strip_tags` removing the space before ` <a>` it just wouldn't happen like that, as `strip_tags` only removes HTML tags, not spaces in front of them.

Comment: Strange ... for some reason these strings are joined. In a wordpress forum found a solution using: preg_replace('/<[a-zA-Z\/][^>]*>/','', $str); before using the function.