# Replace HTML strings with spaces

Tags: php, html, replace, strip-tags

Does anybody know how can I replace HTML string with spaces?

Because if I have something like this

```
<div>word1</div><div>word2</div>
```

when I use strip_tags(), the result is

```
word1word2
```

and I need them to be separated by space in order to be processed the way they should be by my script.

Comment: Use a replace function?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Problem using strip_tags in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4482152/1456376).

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine

```
$str = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', ' ', '<h1>Foo</h1>bar');
```

Afterward use something like

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $input);
```

But you had best not have any stray `<` characters in your text.

Also:

```
preg_replace('/ {2,}/', ' ', $input);
```

will collapse multiple spaces into a single space.

Comment: Your collapse won't iterate enough times to take care of everything ;)

Comment: @ehime it does, I've already run it. I think you're confusing `preg_replace` with `preg_match` and `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, and understandable.

```
<?php

$txt = "<div>word1</div><div>word2</div>";

$find = array("<div>", "</div>");
$replace = array(" ", " ");
echo str_replace($find, $replace, $txt);
```

Comment: You don't need a 2nd array so above can be done like so `echo str_replace(['<div>', '</div>'], ' ', $txt);`